# How to align a button to the center of the screen html

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a button that goes in the centre of the screen I have tried lots of solutions which havent worked html:

```
      <button align="center" type="button" onclick="location.href='https://discord.gg/AsA7P9B5Mv'" class="button">
      <span align="center" class="button__test"> Join Server </span>
      </button>
```

css:

```
  .button {
  text-align: center;
  align: center;
  justify-content: center;  
  align-items: center;  
  height: 10vw;
  width: 25vw;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #10e321;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 1vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 4vw;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.button:hover{
  background: #11d120;
}
.button:active{
  background: #0eb31b;
}
```

Help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use something like this:

```
<div style="text-align:center">  
    <input type="submit" />  
</div>
```

Or you could use something like this. By giving the element a width and specifying auto for the left and right margins the element will center itself in its parent.

```
<input type="submit" style="width: 300px; margin: 0 auto;" />
```

Comment: tnx it works :)

Comment: Glad to hear that. Please checkmark my question when you get a chance.

Comment: yea I wanted to but 10 min wait is pretty annoying especially with simple problems

Answer (score 2):

There is a couple of options to center element, e.g.

1. CSS property `position` - always in the center of the screen

```
.button {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

}
```

2. Flexbox - children element will be always in the center of the parent. You can make the parent full screen.

```
.parent-element {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.class {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="class">
  <button>html</button>
</div>
```